# Bash script without interacting

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to do following:

I have a bash script that calls an interactive command that asks the user for a passphrase. I want to specify the passphrase in the script as a variable, and pass that variable to the command non-interactively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you would like to look into [expect](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/). This utility is designed specifically for typing on behalf of the user.

Assuming your script has a prompt (or a line that dependably appears before user interaction is required), expect can parse the output, and when it sees the line, e.g., 'passphrase:', enter your passphrase and continue execution of the script.

Comment: i would need to inastal expect ant that is not posible in my case. is there any other solution?

Comment: Expect should be a fairly standard tool in the *nix environment, but if it is unavailable, you can try alternative expect implementations, such as [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).  Of course, an alternative will be much bulkier, as you would now need Python (surely available, right?), this pexpect module and for you to execute it from a py script. Luckily, however, it won't require privileged access (which is why I assume you cannot install expect).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very basic technique. Provide an input file to the script. It is a good choice if you don't want to modify the script itself.

I have to use an example that I dreamed up myself.  Here's a basic script prompting the user for values, call it `scp`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Type something: "
read X
echo You gave: $X

echo -n "Type something again: "
read Z
echo This time gave: $Z
```

You can provide an input file as such, call it `input`:

```
value for X
value for Z
```

Then to invoke the script providing `input` for input to the script do this:

```
cat input | ./scp
```

..or alternatively and concisely:

```
./scp < input
```

The output looks like this:

```
Type something: You gave: value for X
Type something again: This time gave: value for Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that your script is this(genrsa.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh 
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Normally, if you execute the genrsa.sh file it will ask for a file name and passphrase twice. Like that:

```
$./genrsa.sh
Enter file name (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase(empty for no passphrase:mypassword
Enter same passphrase:mypassword
public key generated, bla bla bla...
$
```

You want to change the script in a way so you can pass your passphrase as a parameter. So it won't wait for you to type. You will use it like that:

```
$./genrsa.sh mypassword
```

To do that, you have to change your script to something like that(genrsa2.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh   
passphrase=$1
set timeout 2
ssh-keygen -t rsa
expect \"Enter file\" { send \"\r\" }            
expect \"empty for\" { send \"$passphrase\r\" }
expect \"same passphrase\" { send \"$passphrase\r\" }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
${2:-defaultvalue}
```

Where 2 (could be the 1st parameter too) is the second positional parameter and "defaultvalue" is the value the variable takes in case you don't specify any value.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question.